# Reset $q in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am running three different **$http**  calls using $q (Communicate between controller and services).

First I have code to fetch all data from db.

In service,

```
   q = $q.defer();
   $http({ url:"Url/fetchFeeds/", success:function(data){
   d.resolve(data);
   }); 
   return r.promise;
```

For the Controller I use $q.all to wait for ajax completion.

The problem is when I fetch data from second url using same flow (Url/updateFeeds/).  But in console, second ajax call goes to "Url/fetchFeeds/"

How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$q.all` like

```
$q.all([p1.then(thenFn), p2.then(thenFn)])
    .then(function(values) {
        console.log(values);
        return values;
    });
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasBurleson/QqKuk/)

Comment: No actutally, i call both on two different situations, but for second time, its loads only first http url in $q.

Comment: first Http to fetch posts using $q. second to update particular feed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use return promise for your $http call.

```
var callX = function() {    
   return $http({ url:"Url/fetchFeeds/", success:function(data){
       return data;
   });
}
```

You can collect multiple calls in an array and use $q.all.

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(callX().then(...));
promises.push(callY());

$q.all(promises).then(...);
```

Comment: No actutally, i call both on two different situations, but for second time, its loads only first http url in $q.

Comment: Can you show all relevant code? It is difficult to figure out various details for example how do you call second url? how do you use $q.all? etc.